# How parse url to array?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `lists/listA/listB/listC/...`.
Please tell me how I can split the string to this view and write the result to an array:

```
[
  {0: lists},
  {1: lists/listA},
  {2: lists/listA/listB},
  {3: lists/listA/listB/listC},
  {4: lists/listA/listB/listC/...},
  {...: .../...}
]
```

Comment: So, what's the issue you're having with your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO Alex! Please provide some code/ attempt you did. Also try googling "How to split string in Javascript". That should be a good starting point. Then you can work your way to achieve desired output

Comment: Common misconception is that people have to show their attempt. I though the same for a long time.

Comment: Hello Alex, welcome, please read this link to know how can you do a questions that we can help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
let splitedArray = 'lists/listA/listB/listC/...'.split('/');
let string = '';
const result = splitedArray.map((item, index) => {
   return {[index]: string = string + (!index ? item : `/${item}`)};
});
console.log('result', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

strings can be split by `split()` as it is.

```js
let string = 'lists/listA/listB/listC/';

let ans = '';

let arr = string.split('/');

let ansArr = [];

for (let num in arr) {
let obj = new Object();  
num == 0? ans = arr[num] : ans = ans + '/' + arr[num];
obj[num] = ans;
ansArr.push(obj);
}
console.log(ansArr);
/*
let objs = [
  {0: 'lists'},
  {1: 'lists/listA'},
  {2: 'lists/listA/listB'},
  {3: 'lists/listA/listB/listC'},
  {4: 'lists/listA/listB/listC/'}
]

for (let num in objs) {
  console.log(objs[num][num].split('/'))
}
*/
```

Comment: I need to split the string and write it to an array.

Comment: @Alex could you show me the example you expect?

Comment: ```[
  {0: lists},
  {1: lists/listA},
  {2: lists/listA/listB},
  {3: lists/listA/listB/listC},
  {4: lists/listA/listB/listC/...},
  {...: .../...}
]```

Comment: @Alex so the string `lists/listA/listB/listC/...` is the problem and the array is actually the answer?

Comment: @Alex edited and check please.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```js
let url = 'lists/listA/listB/listC';
// declare variable to save result
let arrUrl = [];

// split url with / and append each part and push into arrUrl.
url.split('/').forEach((part, index) => {
  if (index == 0) {
    arrUrl.push({
      [index]: part
    });
  } else {
    arrUrl.push({
      [index]: arrUrl[index - 1][index - 1] + '/' + part
    });
  }
});

console.log(arrUrl);
```

---

**Edit** From your comment it seems that you want something like below.

```js
let url = 'lists/listA/listB/listC';
// declare variable to save result
let arrUrl = [];

// split url with / and append each part and push into arrUrl.
url.split('/').forEach((part, index) => {
  if (index == 0) {
    arrUrl.push(part);
  } else {
    arrUrl.push(arrUrl[index - 1] + '/' + part);
  }
});

console.log(arrUrl);
```

Comment: thanks, but the result is not the same

Comment: Can you please check answer from both snippet and confirm is that your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'lists/listA/listB/listC'

const output = input.split('/').map((v, i, arr) => ({
  [i]: arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('/')
}))

console.log(output)
```